# Print array in console

Tags: javascript

I have a newbie question. How do i print this info in the console? 
 [the object shown in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJicd.jpg)
I have an object that is not a DOM element and it has an array inside. 
I print the object but I need to get the elements of the array.

How do I print the children of "bannerdata"?

I wrote: console.log(varName.bannerdata);

That is as far as i get.

Comment: Your `console.log` statement seems right. What's the problem?

Comment: Output the JSON text for that object: `console.log(JSON.stringify(varName.bannerdata));`

Comment: You can also click on those arrows like you opened the first one for the array, it will open the object and you will be able to see their structure. Really this is a convenience thing Chrome does, if you want the un-fancy version do what @trincot suggests.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just click the little "Arrow" next to your object item, item in array will expand and you will get the properties for object stored in the array.

Or use `JSON.stringify(yourArrayHere)` as @trincot suggested, example:

```js
var bannerData = [{item:1},{item:2},{item:3}];
console.log(JSON.stringify(bannerData));
```

JSON.stringify() method will convert a JavaScript value/object to a JSON string.

If you are interested in learning more about Chrome Developer tools including use of API console.log() and other tricks, you can start by reading the following:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

http://tutorialzine.com/2015/03/15-must-know-chrome-devtools-tips-tricks/

Comment: I tryied what @trincot suggested but i get "null" like its shown in the image because dataBanner its "null" but it has children that I dont know the command to get them.

Comment: I get null for how is coded the application. The answer its ok